# Firefox doesn't launch in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: firefox, launcher, sudo, 13.04

Firefox starts when I use sudo in the terminal, but not from the launcher. All the other apps work like a charm, just not Firefox. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try starting firefox in terminal *without* sudo.  Do you see any errors?

Comment: When you try to start Firefox from the terminal, you'll see the error message. A proper solution is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29856330/453673

Answer (score 12):

To fix this issue execute the following commands

```
chown -hR YOUR_USER .gnome2/
chown -hR YOUR_USER .gnome2_private/
```

Comment: I did not have a `.gnome2_private/` directory, but changing ownership on the `.gnome2/` seemed to do the trick. Thanks. Just as a note, this was only happening to me the first time I opened firefox after a reboot. If I closed it and then re-opened it via the launcher, it would work.

Comment: I have none of these directories (i'm running on icewm)

Answer (score 0):

## Reset Firefox

Run this command in Terminal:

```
rm -r ~/.mozilla
```

NOTE : This will erase your bookmarks, history..etc.

Comment: Beware! This will delete all your bookmarks, browsing history, addons, and other customizations.

Comment: This does not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

chown did it. But you must run as root:

```
sudo -i

[type password]

chown -hR $USER .gnome2/

chown -hR $USER .gnome2_private/
```

Comment: In which directory?

Comment: When you open terminal you are on your home folder by default. All that folders are inside of it, so you can only type as described above and replace "YOUR_USER" by your username.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and sudo -i took me to the folder `/root`. I used the last 2 commands with the prefix `sudo`