# FireFox doesn't start in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, firefox

Clicking on the FireFox icon in the Unity launcher bar doesn't work. Icon start blinking and after few seconds it simply stop blinking and nothing else happens and FireFox doesn't start.

OS release is Ubuntu 13.10 (3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:17:04 UTC 2013). Currently installed version of FireFox is  26.0

Trying from a Terminal gives the following error messages:

```
(process:5576): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
(firefox:5576): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised
(firefox:5576): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised
```

...

and finally permission refused on /home/myaccount/.gnome2/accels when it attempted to create Gnome keyboard shortcuts folder.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What if you run `firefox` in a terminal?

Comment: I get the following:
(process:5576): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:5576): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

and finally permission refused on /home/myaccount/.gnome2

Comment: I get the following:
(process:5576): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:5576): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:5576): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

...

and finally permission refused on /home/myaccount/.gnome2/accels when it attempted to create Gnome keyboard shortcuts folder.

Comment: I found same kind of issue in post #284981 and same solution worked for me:
sudo chown -hR <myaccount>:<myaccount> .gnome2
sudo chown -hR <myaccount>:<myaccount> .gnome2_private

Sorry for my question, I should have dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

I found same kind of issue in [post #284981](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284981/firefox-doesnt-launch-in-ubuntu-13-04) and same solution worked for me:

```
sudo chown -hR $USER:$USER .gnome2
sudo chown -hR $USER:$USER .gnome2_private
```

Credit should go to [Paulo](https://askubuntu.com/users/152499/paulo) who provided the solution.